# update a column depending on the value of another column using case

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to update a column depending on the value of another column.
Something like this :

```
update mt
set
 case 
  when mt.type = 1  (1=float 2=boolean 3=datetime 4=character)
  then mt.float_value = mt.value
 end

 case 
  when mt.type = 2  (1=float 2=boolean 3=datetime 4=character)
  then mt.boolean_value = mt.value
 end

case 
  when mt.type = 3  (1=float 2=boolean 3=datetime 4=character)
  then mt.datetime_value = mt.value
 end
...
from myTable mt
```

I want to update the column mt.float_value or mt.boolean_value or mt.datetime_value or mt.char_value depending on the value of the column mt.type

```
if the column mt.type = 1 then update mt.float_value with  mt.value
if the column mt.boolean_value = 2 then update mt.float_value with  mt.value
```

and so on...
Is that possible and how can I perform this update?
Thanks for help

Comment: Whenever you are populating only one of many columns in each row of a table you ought to ask if the schema is appropriate. For example, if you want to store key/value pairs where the value could be any data type then it probably makes more sense to have separate tables for each data type rather than a single wide table with columns for all possible data types. Triggers can be used to ensure that a given key doesn't have multiple values of various data types. Aside: It's also curious that your query lacks a `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You could split it in three queries:

```
update  mt
set     float_value = convert(value, float)
where   type = 1

update  mt
set     bit_value = convert(value, bit)
where   type = 2

update  mt
set     datetime_value = convert(value, datetime)
where   type = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, but it will fail if any of the values cannot be converted to their destination column types:

```
update mt
set 
 mt.float_value = case 
  when mt.type = 1  then convert(mt.value, float) else mt.float_value
 end,

 mt.boolean_value = case 
  when mt.type = 2  then convert(mt.value, bit) else mt.boolean_value
 end,

mt.datetime_value = case 
  when mt.type = 3  then  convert(mt.value, datetime) else mt.datetime_value
 end
...
from myTable mt
```

Comment: You could avoid the conversion errors with [`try_convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)